# Stack smashing detected after one successful

Tags: c, memory, out-of-memory

In my trouble, after a correct output time (maybe more time) when i executed program the second lead to "stack smashing detected" error! (i execute the same binary).
Who find out the problem here?? why ?
my command:

> phuocblack@phuocblack-X455LAB:~/.project$ gcc TEST.c -o a
> phuocblack@phuocblack-X455LAB:~/.project$ ./a 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 12 22 66
> phuocblack@phuocblack-X455LAB:~/.project$ ./a
> -1591423488 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 12 22
> *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a terminated Aborted (core dumped)

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void swapp(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(void) 
{   
    int i = 0;
    int arr[10] = {12,3,4,5,2,66,7,1,22,3};
    
    while (i < 10)
    {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[i+1])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            swapp(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

PLEASE EXPLAIN HOW IT SHOW and the memory problem here! i am a new@@

Comment: The expression `if (arr[i] <= arr[i+1])` will cause out-of-bounds access to the array. i.e `arr[10]`, as will `swapp(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);`.

Comment: so why the first time, it is correct!?

Comment: When `i == 9` then `i+1 = 10`, then `arr[i+1]` accesses `arr[10]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when your parameter `i == 9` you are trying to access to 10th cell, which you don't have.
This mistake is in 2 places: `if (arr[i] <= arr[i+1])` and `swapp(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);`.
Here fixed code which is work:

```
    while (i < 10 && i + 1 < 10) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[i + 1])
            i++;
        else {
            swapp(&arr[i], &arr[i + 1]);
            if (i > 0)
                i--;
        }
    }
```

Another problem is you are working on `C` platform so change the line:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

to:

```
    i = 0;
    for (i; i < 10; i++)
```

The reason is you can't set the variable again within the loop.